# Can I have two ACTIVE games at once?

Tags: windows-10

Ok, so I am wanting to play Don't Starve Together splitscreen on PC. I've done a LOT of research to no avail. There's no `.ini` file. Don't tell me to "Get a PS4." Don't tell me to "Get another computer." I'm trying to run TWO instances on ONE computer. Is this possible?

I'd prefer using 1 kb/m for both players, or even 1kb/m for one player and one controller for the other, just NOT two controllers.

Please don't close this as duplicate. The answers there didn't help.

Comment: Just a suggestion:  Get 2 monitor so both can see everything.

Comment: Run one in a VM (or each in a separate VM)?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, with this mod below the answer is **YES**

> https://github.com/r-mach/nucleuscoop
>
> Nucleus Co-Op is a tool for Windows that allows split-screen play on many games that do not initially support it. Its purpose is to make it as easy as possible for the average user to play games locally.
>
> Support its development by helping on my Patreon! https://www.patreon.com/distro
>   Subscribe to our subreddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/nucleuscoop/
>
> > Currently Supported Games:
> >
> > - Borderlands 1
> > - Borderlands 2
> > - Borderlands: The Pre Sequel
> > - Don't Starve Together
> > - Left 4 Dead 2

I have not tried this myself, but a quick google search found the above information.

One user suggested this js file might be necessary.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfn1m.jpg

https://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/70774-pc-split-screen/?page=2

The last 2 posters above got it to work, and one of them even said "no bugs".

Your mileage may vary